I joists not making contact with beam
My basement has I joists running continuously from the concrete foundation. There is a part of the house that bumps out making for a longer span in that area. The builder decided to add a beam there to help support it even though it is only 3 feet from the foundation. Unfortunately most of the joists aren’t making contact with the beam. They are about 1/8th inch off. The result is we have a problem area there with floor deflection that is noticeably worse than the rest of the house.
I’m wondering how we can shore up this area to help with the bounce.
image of area 
closeup showing gap

Looks like the area is begging for shims.

@RMDman , that's the answer, but need to elaborate, when the shims are added and the beam starts to truly take on the weight, where the shims were initially driven to, once the other shims are added, will need to be driven in an additional amount. All shims will need to be "tuned up" in this fashion. IMO, the floor will always have movement, this will reduce it, but not eliminate it. It will never be like a concrete floor.
